# Access properties(objects) in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

Looks like this should have been fairly easy task, but I'm kinda stuck.

Basically I am using a web service which returns JSON. In a debugger if I do something like

```
data.d
```

I am getting following JSON object.

```
{
   "d":[
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "uri":"http://service.cloud.net/FooService.svc/ZooInfoes(1)",
            "type":"Fun.Sun"
         },
         "Status":2,
         "GoingFishing":false
      }
   ]
}
```

However,

```
data.d[0]
```

just returns "**{**" and

```
data.d.Status
```

returns "**undefined**"

Could someone help me to access Status or uri values?

Comment: It seems that the value of `data.d` is a string containing JSON. You have to parse that JSON first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data.d` gives you `{"d": ...}`, then you want `data.d.d[0].Status`, or if you have a string, `JSON.parse(data.d).d[0].Status`

Comment: `data.d.d[0].Status` is not returning anything but `JSON.parse(data.d).d[0].Status` is giving perfect result! 

Thank you!